# Apple Printer driver for Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apple

Will anyone tell me where to download Ubuntu 18.04 printer drivers to run my Apple LaserWriter Select 360 printer?  Both the Apple Printer and Dell Port Pro2X have parallel and serial cable connections.

Comment: https://www.openprinting.org/driver/Postscript/

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/cups.html  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkPrintingWithUbuntu maybe also helpful.